# Regexp for different characters in row

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that will match strings like "ab", "xy", but not "aa", or "xx".

I know opposite one, `/(.)\1/` - it finds the same chars, but how to make regex that will match 2 different characters?

It would be part of more complex regex, so suggestions like `!string.match?(/(.)\1/)` are not acceptable unfortunately.

Comment: `\w{2}` no?......

Comment: @Berto99 it also matches "aa", so no

Comment: I think you want `(.)(?!\1).` Or a bit more specific `([a-z])(?!\1)[a-z]`

Comment: yes, it is! @Thefourthbird could you make it an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match 2 chars where the second is not equal to the first, you can assert before matching the second char that it is not the same as what is already captured in group 1 by adding the backreference to a negative lookahead.

If that assertion is true, match the second char.

```
(.)(?!\1).
```

For lowercase chars a-z the pattern would look like

```
([a-z])(?!\1)[a-z]
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D5lCqw/1)